# stop chrome extension if identity check fails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement an identity check for my chrome extension since I want to sell it to some users.
The code below is usig the `chrome.identity` API to get the unique OpenID in combination with the email that is logged in. Then it is fetching data from a pastebin and checks if the id is included or not.
If not I would want to block the user from using the extension. What would be the best approach?

My code:

```
// license check
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo({ 'accountStatus': 'ANY' }, async function (info) {
    email = info.email;
    console.log(info.id);

    let response = await fetch('https://pastebin.com/*****');
    let data = await response.text();

    console.log(data.indexOf(info.id));

    if (data.indexOf(info.id) !== -1) {
        console.log('included');
    } else {
        console.log('not included');
        // block chrome extension usage;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty simple solution that should work for most cases.

```
// license check
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo({ 'accountStatus': 'ANY' }, async function (info) {
    email = info.email;
    console.log(info.id);

    let response = await fetch('https://pastebin.com/*****');
    let data = await response.text();

    console.log(data.indexOf(info.id));

    if (data.indexOf(info.id) !== -1) {
        console.log('included');
    } else {
        console.log('not included');
        // block chrome extension usage;
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: 'index.html' }); // index.html has to 
                                                                   be in the 
                                                                   extension folder and can have e. g. a <h1> which says "Invalid license"

    }
});
```